# how to customize nested fields serializer through another serializer in drf

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization, crud

**File** class and **Animation** are related together
And I want to somehow implement the following code
`serial = AnimationSerializer(instance=Animation.objects.get(id=animationn_id), fields=["duration", "age_rating", {"file": ["name", "description"]}])`
or
`serial = FileSerializer(instance=File.objects.get(id=file_id), fields=["name", "description", {"animations": {"fields": ["duration", "made_by"], "many": True, "read_only": False}}])`

actually i don't want write several serializer class.
I want to write as little code as possible to achieve this goal.

I want to implement the methods of creation and retrieval and update  for two models using 2 serializers so that I can use one of the two serializers to create, retrieve, and update instances of that one model.

i have two simple model :

```
class File(models.Model):
    video = 1
    PDF = 2
    word = 3
    all_types = (
    (video, "video"),
    (PDF, "PDF"),
    (word, "word"),
    )
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=all_types)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Animation(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey("File", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="animations")
    duration = models
    made_by = models..CharField(max_length=30)
    age_rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[validators.MaxValueValidator(24)])
```

and i have these serializer class:

```
class DynamicFieldsCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

class FileSerializer(DynamicFieldsCategorySerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = "__all__"

class AnimationSerializer(DynamicFieldsCategorySerializer):
    file = FileSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Animation
        fields = "__all__"
```

according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72156378/drf-how-to-select-specific-fields-to-display-in-a-nested-serializer-relationship) i write DynamicFieldsCategorySerializer class for customizing AnimationSerializer fields. but i want costomize FileSerializer through AnimationSerializer

one way for retrieve method is this:

```
class FileSerializer(DynamicFieldsCategorySerializer):
    animations = AnimationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = "__all__"
    animation_fields = []
    def get_animations(self, obj):
        return AnimationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, instance=obj.animations, fields=self.animation_fields).data
```

and get data in this way :

```
serial = FileSerializer(instance=File.objects.get(id=file_id))
serial.animation_fields.extend(["name", "description"])
serial.data
```

but this way is good just for retrieve method and i want do all CRUD methods
I thinks it is possible by override **build_field**, **build_nested_field**, **get_nested_relation_kwargs **in source code django rest framwork
I think that such a goal can be achieved by override the **build_field**and **build_nested_field**and **get_nested_relation_kwargs**methods in the source code of Django Rest Framework. But i do not know how